# JSON Object is not resolved before Controller is instantiated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic to create an app, and in the controller, I'm getting an object that's resolved from the app.js. This object has several properties including an array like so:

```
{
    "objectId":"id",
    "objectName":"name",
    "anArray":[{
        "id":"id1",
        "name":"name1",
        "description":"Medium Rare",
        "photographUrl":"/image1"
    }, {
        "id":"id2",
        "name":"name2",
        "description":"Baked Beans on Scrumptious Dark Rye Bread",
        "photographUrl":"/image2"
    }],
    "emptyArray":[]
}
```

However, the problem is, I can iterate through each item in the array in the html using: (key, value)  in theObject.anArray, but in the controller, I'm trying to iterate through the array in a for loop
   `for (var i = 0; i < $scope.theObject.anArray.length; i++) {...}`

However, I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Can anyone help me figure out why I cannot access this array in the controller, but I can in the html. In fact, I can't access any property of the object in the controller, It appears as if the controller is instantiated before the object is resolved in the app.js using 'resolve', however, I was under the impression that this isn't supposed to happen, that the data was supposed to be resolved before the controller is instantiated

P.S. in the controller I use this:

```
$scope.theObject = theObject;
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you do console.log($scope.theObject) ?

Comment: Just returns [object Object]

Comment: can we get more about that $scope.theObject? where is it coming from?

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.theObject)).. 
Check the structure of object. See if the key exists or not.

Comment: JSON.stringify() returns {}. The key does exist, and works in the HTML using ng-repeat="(key, value)  in theObject.anArray  The Object is being coming from a web request, a query on a $resource. The Object returned is correct as can be seen from the network activity.

Comment: do you get the object via http? WHEN does your iteration start, are you sure the http-request is done before you start iterating?

Comment: Hi Johan, using $resource.query(), using        resolve: {
          listOfMeals: ['$stateParams', 'mealsFactory', function($stateParams, mealsFactory) {
            return mealsFactory.listOfMeals().get({date: $stateParams.date});
          }]   I'm pretty sure, but how can i fiind out?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I've solved the problem. Resolve returns a promise for the object before the controller is instantiated. However, the controller is instantiated before the object data from the web call is put into that promise object. So the solution is to make the web call inside the controller using this line

```
factory.theObject().get().$promise.then(function (response{
   $scope.theObject = response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting below error because you don't have `JSON`. You have an array: `[]`.

[image]

**Try this :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    var theObject = [{
    "objectId":"id",
    "objectName":"name",
    "anArray":[{
        "id":"id1",
        "name":"name1",
        "description":"Medium Rare",
        "photographUrl":"/image1"
    }, {
        "id":"id2",
        "name":"name2",
        "description":"Baked Beans on Scrumptious Dark Rye Bread",
        "photographUrl":"/image2"
    }],
    "emptyArray":[]
}];
$scope.theObject = theObject;
var arr = $scope.theObject[0].anArray;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i]);
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work, I get this error:TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object. The object passed isn't an array, but an object that has an array as one it's properties. The object being passed is from a Rest Controller, so I can't change that